# Netty NioClientSocketChannelFactory - Efficient Constructor Parameters

Tags: netty

I'm using netty to send multiple client requests and was wondering how best to configure the NioClientSocketChannelFactory. i.e:

`NioClientSocketChannelFactory.NioClientSocketChannelFactory(Executor bossExecutor, Executor workerExecutor, int workerCount)`

I have a single ClientBootstrap and Channel and am writing multiple requests to different hosts, and am not setting and bootstrap options. As an example I may be pushing through 100 requests using an iterator.

How should I configure this?
I've tried different combinations of Single and Cached Pool Executors with either 1 or 100 max workers.  Here are some examples:

1. When using a single executor and 1 worker it seems to provide multithreaded requests but when setting the count to 100 it appears single threaded
2. When using the Cached Pool Executor, setting the count to 1 also seems more efficient. Increasing the worker count seems to make it slower.

So... how should I configure the factory for best performance based on wanting hundreds or more concurrent requests?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use cached thread pools and let Netty decide the worker count based on available processors, or simply:

```
... = new NioClientSocketChannelFactory();
```

Comment: Assume you mean "new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(Executor bossExecutor, Executor workerExecutor)"??

Comment: @thomascrabs No, I meant what I wrote. That constructor will use cached  executors for boss and workers.